# UWP RadExpanderControl is binding ContentTemplate but not ExpandableContentTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, telerik

the idea here is that every revision of a file spawns a new file with a name that adds "_v1", "_v2", etc. The back end gets the files from disk and groups them based on that name. So a header might say "example", then when you click on the expander, you see "example", "example_v1", "example_v2", etc.

However, when this grouped data reaches the front-end, only the keys are showing, with an empty list of expanded content. Is my XAML messed up or is it something else?

This is MainPage.xaml:

```
<my:RadDataBoundListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <my:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my1:RadExpanderControl
                Content="{ Binding }"
                ExpandableContent="{ Binding }"
                IsExpanded="True">
                <my1:RadExpanderControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Key }" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my1:RadExpanderControl.ContentTemplate>
                <my1:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Name }" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my1:RadExpanderControl.ExpandableContentTemplate>
            </my1:RadExpanderControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
</my:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

This is from MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    CollectionViewSource cvs = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        cvs.Source = ViewModel.Files;
        cvs.IsSourceGrouped = true;
        listBox.ItemsSource = (IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Files>>)cvs.Source;
    }
}
```

This is from the ViewModel:

```
private IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Files>> files;

public IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Files>> Files
{
    get
    {
        if (files ==  null)
        {
            var source = Source;
            string[] separaters = { "_", "." };
            files = from file in source
                    group file by file.Name.Split(separaters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
                    into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select g;
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

This is how the list of filenames is pulled from disk:

```
public ObservableCollection<Files> Source
{
    get
    {
        return GetFilesData(Folder).Result;
    }
}
```

This is the model for the filenames:

```
public class Files
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, are you using Telerik's `RadDataBoundListBox`? If not, can you provide the code for the custom control?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Yes, that's what I'm using. Appreciate the help!